# How do I get into Lab 19?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

I've found the entrance to Lab 19, and I'm at the part of the mission where it asks me to enter the authentication code in order to open the door.  I head to the room with the authenticator, and I can see it, but can't do anything with it.

[image: Authenticator on the wall.]

If I jump close to it, I get a chance to interact with it, but nothing happens.  I've tried interacting with it then running back to Lab 19 to activate that console, but it says I still haven't entered the proper code.  There's another console in the room that I've tried using, but it doesn't seem to do anything either.  It seems like the game wants me to detach the authenticator from the wall and take it with me, but shooting or meleeing it doesn't do anything, and I can't get the robotic arm to move either, which would seem like the obvious solution.

Am I just doing this wrong, or missing something simple here?  Does this need to be done in a co-op game?  I don't know, and need a little help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a code panel on the wall above and to the right of the door that you're trying to open.  You need to shoot the arrows on the left and right of the numbers to change them to what you read on the authenticator, then use the control panel to open the door.  Everything in the room with the authenticator is just a red herring at this point, except for the values on the authenticator.

Obviously this is easier to do with 2 or more players, as one can stand at the panel in Lab 19 while the other reads the numbers from the authenticator, but there is more than enough time to do it solo, if you read the value as soon as it changes and book it back to Lab 19.

[Credit where credit is due](http://auluftwaffles.com/2014/10/16/how-to-open-the-lab-19-vault-in-lab-19-in-borderlands-the-pre-sequel/)